# CS50 PSET 4 "Speller" - Having issues freeing allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

I'm programming a spellchecker per CS50's Week 4 problem set, but I ran into an issue. I am leaking memory.

```
:) dictionary.c exists
:) speller compiles
:) handles most basic words properly
:) handles min length (1-char) words
:) handles max length (45-char) words
:) handles words with apostrophes properly
:) spell-checking is case-insensitive
:) handles substrings properly
:( program is free of memory errors
    valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.
```

As shown above, I'm passing all the tests except the last one.

My code (**dictionary.c**):

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 390;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// # of words in dict
unsigned int numWords = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary (case insensitive), else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int index = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[index];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    // use a 2d array -> x-axis = first letter of word (a-z), y-axis = size of word (1-15)
    // 390 buckets (26 x 15)

    int first_letter = tolower(word[0]) - '`'; // gets the value of each inital letter (1-26)
    int word_length = strlen(word);
    int index = first_letter * word_length;

    if (index > N)
    {
        return N - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return index;
    }
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (!file) // checks if file can be opened
    {
        return false;
    }

    char word_list[LENGTH];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word_list) != EOF) // reads one word
    {
        node *node_word = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (node_word == NULL) // checks if there is enough memory for the node
        {
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(node_word->word, word_list); // copies the already read word into the node
        // prepends each new word in a linked list at table[index]
        int index = hash(word_list); // finds which index this word belongs in the hash table
        if (table[index] == NULL) // checks if there are any words in linked-list
        {
            table[index] = node_word; // the root points to newly-"read" word and that word marks beginning of linked list
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *next = table[index]; // creates a node that points beginning of linked list at that index
            table[index] = node_word; // the root points to our newly-"read" word
            node_word->next = next; // newly-"read" word points to "second" (if there is one) word in linked list
        }
        numWords++; // increments numWords, which is returned in size()
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return numWords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) // starts at one since indexing starts at one
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, I load in a "dictionary" and scan a piece of text to see if any of the words in it are "misspelled" (or not in the aforementioned dictionary). But, the problem is that the dictionary is not being freed or unloaded.

Link to assignment instructions: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/5/speller/

I tried using Valgrind on different texts and I got varying results. For texts without any misspellings (e.g. cat.txt and pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.txt) I got:

```
==24212== 
==24212== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24212==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24212==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,096 frees, 8,023,256 bytes allocated
==24212== 
==24212== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24212== 
==24212== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==24212== ERROR SUMMARY: 193 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But when I load in all texts that do have misspellings (the rest of them), I get:

```
==24578== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==24578==    at 0x4A5CA35: write (write.c:26)
==24578==    by 0x49D2F6C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1180)
==24578==    by 0x49D4A60: new_do_write (fileops.c:448)
==24578==    by 0x49D4A60: _IO_new_do_write (fileops.c:425)
==24578==    by 0x49D4A60: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:422)
==24578==    by 0x49D3754: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1243)
==24578==    by 0x49D3754: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1196)
==24578==    by 0x49BE049: outstring_func (vfprintf-internal.c:239)
==24578==    by 0x49BE049: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1593)
==24578==    by 0x49A881E: printf (printf.c:33)
==24578==    by 0x10964F: main (speller.c:122)
==24578== 
==24578== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24578==     in use at exit: 8,018,688 bytes in 143,094 blocks
**==24578==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 2 frees, 8,023,256 bytes allocated // correct amount of allocs, wrong amount of frees**
==24578== 
==24578== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==24578==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24578==    by 0x49C76CD: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==24578==    by 0x49C76CD: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==24578==    by 0x109388: main (speller.c:55)
==24578== 
==24578== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==24578==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24578==    by 0x49C6C23: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==24578==    by 0x49D5D5F: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==24578==    by 0x49D4FDF: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:744)
==24578==    by 0x49D3754: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1243)
==24578==    by 0x49D3754: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1196)
==24578==    by 0x49BD1CC: outstring_func (vfprintf-internal.c:239)
==24578==    by 0x49BD1CC: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1263)
==24578==    by 0x49A881E: printf (printf.c:33)
==24578==    by 0x1093D1: main (speller.c:64)
==24578== 
==24578== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==24578==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24578==    by 0x49C6C23: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==24578==    by 0x49D5D5F: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==24578==    by 0x49D3543: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1287)
==24578==    by 0x49C7C28: fread (iofread.c:38)
==24578==    by 0x10940A: main (speller.c:72)
==24578== 
==24578== 8,013,096 bytes in 143,091 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==24578==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24578==    by 0x109A51: load (dictionary.c:80)
==24578==    by 0x1092DB: main (speller.c:40)
==24578== 
==24578== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24578==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24578==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24578==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24578==    still reachable: 8,018,688 bytes in 143,094 blocks
==24578==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24578== 
==24578== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==24578== ERROR SUMMARY: 543 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

On the bolded line, I noticed the expected amount of allocs (the # of words in the dictionary), but an incorrect amount of frees. I don't know why it only frees 2 times and how it's leaking memory in files that I haven't touched.
As instructed, I am not able to change the code of these files:
**speller.c**

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

**dictionary.h**

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

This file allows me to use the command 'make' in the terminal as opposed to its longer clang equivalent.
**Makefile**

```
speller:
    clang -ggdb3 -gdwarf-4 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
    clang -ggdb3 -gdwarf-4 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
    clang -ggdb3 -gdwarf-4 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o -lm
```

Thanks!

Comment: Examine this comment: `// starts at one since indexing starts at one` and the definition of the array that is being free()'d : `node *table[N];` ,,, In C, indexing starts at `0` and goes to `N-1`. There are `N` elements. (eg: arr[5] has valid elements indexed from 0 to 4...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 I have it starting at 1 since I use it for indexing with table. I know table[0] will be  NULL since I haven't allocated anything to it in my load function. This happens because my hash function only returns integers above 0. My load function allocates into table[index] with index being the return value of my hash function, which again, is never 0.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I don't know what they are referring to by log. I assumed it was Valgrind, but let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: @nzo It's valgrind alright, but it may be more specific than your own valgrind run. I think you should try to find the log the test is talking about. If not for this exercise, then for all to come.

Comment: Fwiw, valgrind output can be hard to read (I think it often is). You can also compile your program with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined,leak` and then run the program normally (without valgrind). Not only is it faster than valgrind, the output (if anything "bad" is found) is usually much easier to interpret (my personal opinion).

Comment: The reason why Valgrind was printing errors was because the program prints out all the misspelled words, and thus, larger texts print for quite a while. Thus, I would use CTRL + C to exit out of the program quicker, but I thought that it wouldn't affect anything since Valgrind still gave results afterwards. Now, I let it run on and Valgrind outputs as expected, but when I use check50, I still don't pass the last test.

Comment: _"My load function allocates into table[index]"_ Well, that will exhibit UB when `index` is the same value as the size of the arrary... But, maybe you know better... (PS: Being conventional by starting the loop at 0 will still work; the NULL at `arr[0]` will be skipped the same way the other unused elements of the hashtable are skipped...)

Comment: Hint: This line: `if (index > N) { return N - 1; }` will likely _populate_ the last element of the hashtable with an unreasonably large number of nodes. Consider using `modulo` (ie: `return index % N` instead. This might build a word chain from `arr[0]` but won't try to populate the nonexistent `arr[N]`. And, it will 'distribute' "high value hashes" so the blind search to the end for misspelled words searches shorter chains...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thanks for the help, but I still don't pass the last test. Though, I will certainly keep your suggestion.

Comment: Fix the segfault first. Applications that do not exit cleanly will have meaningless leak summaries.

Comment: Final comment: The generated hash values (products of multiplying) will never be prime. Since there's almost 80 primes between 1 and 400, about 80% of your hashtable will be used (leaving 20% empty). Finding a better hashing function may pay dividends in speed. So too would terminating early when a misspelled word not found in the "reverse sorted" LL that is being searched. (There's no need to always search to the very end of the LL...) Good luck!